# How to insert multiple records into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I insert multiple records into a database using rails syntax.

```
INSERT INTO users (email,name) VALUES ('a@ao.in','a'),('b@ao.in','b'),
                                      ('c@ao.in','c');
```

This is how we do it in MySQL. How is this done in Rails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use following in my project but it is not proper for sql injection.
if you are not using user input in this query it may work for you

```
user_string = " ('a@ao.in','a'), ('b@ao.in','b')"
User.connection.insert("INSERT INTO users (email, name) VALUES"+user_string)
```

Answer (score 14):

Check out this blog post: http://www.igvita.com/2007/07/11/efficient-updates-data-import-in-rails/

```
widgets = [ Widget.new(:title => 'gizmo', :price => 5),
            Widget.new(:title => 'super-gizmo', :price => 10)]
Widget.import widgets
```

Depending on your version of rails, use activerecord-import 0.2.6 (for Rails 3) and ar-extensions 0.9.4 (for Rails 2)

From the author: http://www.continuousthinking.com/tags/arext

Comment: I used ar-extensions 0.9.4 since my rails version is 2.3.5. But still when I execute this statement, Two insert queries are being executed.

Comment: Amal, did you get it figured out? If not, please update your post here to show what you're doing or ask a new question with more detailed information.

Comment: I was able to fix my issue using this method.                user_string = " ('a@ao.in','a'), ('b@ao.in','b')"
User.connection.insert("INSERT INTO users (email, name) VALUES"+user_string). I tried all other methods specified here, but in all other case more than 1 insert query were being executed

Comment: I had the same requirement of loading data from a CSV into a table.  This solution directly answered the question being asked, resulting in just one INSERT.  I found this was MUCH faster than an individual `.first_or_initialize()` (Rails 4 here) for each line in the CSV.

Answer (score 12):

While you cannot get the exact SQL that you have there, you can insert multiple records by passing create or new on an array of hashes:

```
new_records = [
  {:column => 'value', :column2 => 'value'}, 
  {:column => 'value', :column2 => 'value'}
]

MyModel.create(new_records)
```

Comment: On executing this two insert queries were performed.

Comment: How can we make it execute only one insert query and insert both the records.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible with ActiveRecord. You might want to check out this post and ar-extensions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256898/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-based-on-a-query

Answer (score 4):

Just a use activerecord-import gem for rails 3 or ar-extensions for rails 2

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki

In Gemfile:

```
gem "activerecord-import"
```

In model:

```
import "activerecord-import"
```

In controller:

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```

This code import 10 records by one query ;)

or

```
#@messages = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@content)
@messages = JSON(@content)

#prepare data for insert by one insert
fields = [:field1, :field2]
items = []
@messages.each do |m|
    items << [m["field1"], m["field2"]]
end

Message.import fields, items
```

Comment: Its important to note, that activerecord-import doesn't return the ids of the inserted rows.

Comment: Good recommendation. The gem runs one query.

Answer (score 0):

In People_controller.rb

```
# POST people

NAMES = ["Sokly","Nary","Mealea"]

def create
    Person.transaction do
        NAMES.each do |name|
            @name = Person.create(:name => name)
            @name.save
        end
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fast Seeder](https://github.com/greyblake/fast_seeder) to do multiple insert.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass an array of hashs to the create method like this:

```
User.create([{:email => "foo@com", :name => "foo"}, {:email => "bar@com", :name => "bar"}])
```

Comment: On executing this two insert queries were performed.

Comment: you'd better to notice this in your question