# How can I optimize this ruby script?

Tags: mysql, ruby, optimization

I have this code, and it takes a LONG time.

When I used -r profile it indicated that most of the time appears to go to mysql... how can I speed this up? MySQL Bulk inserts?

Profiler output is here: http://pastebin.com/fH51ZeEB

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mysql'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
begin
i=0
src = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'me', 'pass', 'db'
rs = src.query("SELECT * FROM npanxx")
rs.each_hash do |row|
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://localcallingguide.com/xmllocalprefix.php?npa="<< row["npa"].to_s << "&nxx=" << row["nxx"].to_s << "&dir=1"))
  lca = Hash.new
  doc.xpath("//prefix/npa | //prefix/nxx | //prefix/exch").each do |prefix|
    if !lca.has_key? "npa"
      lca["npa"] = prefix.content 
      next
    end
    if !lca.has_key? "nxx"
      lca["nxx"] = prefix.content 
      next
    end
    if !lca.has_key? "exch"
      lca["exch"] = prefix.content 
      src.query("INSERT INTO npanxxlca (npa,nxx,tnpa,tnxx,texch) VALUES (#{row['npa']}, #{row['nxx']}, #{lca['npa']}, #{lca['nxx']}, #{lca['exch']})")
      lca = Hash.new
    end
  end
  puts (i+=1).to_s << "- #{row['npa']}, #{row['nxx']}\n"
end
rescue Mysql::Error => e
    puts e.errno
    puts e.error
ensure
    src.close if src
end
```

Comment: Seems more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since this code actually works, no?

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that one existed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) with [Hydra](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/typhoeus/typhoeus/Typhoeus/Hydra) you can do [requests in parallel](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests). It allows to set custom [max concurrency](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#specifying-max-concurrency) (`200` is default).
Instead of parsing `XML` with [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) and search for values by `XPath` multiple times and storing into new hash every time, you just can parse `XML` directly into hash object using [crack](https://github.com/jnunemaker/crack):

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'typhoeus'
require 'mysql'
require 'crack'
require 'json'

BASE_URL ||= 'http://localcallingguide.com/xmllocalprefix.php'.freeze

HOST     ||= 'localhost'.freeze
USER     ||= 'me'.freeze
PASSWORD ||= 'pass'.freeze
DATABASE ||= 'db'.freeze

#
# Build lca request based on provided npa and nxx
# @param [Integer, String] npa - NPA
# @param [Integer, String] nxx - NXX
# @return [Typhoeus::Request] - request object
def lca_request(npa, nxx)
  Typhoeus::Request.new(BASE_URL, params: { dir: 1, npa: npa, nxx: nxx })
end

#
# Convert XML string into Hash object
# @param [String] xml - XML string to convert
# @return [Hash] Ruby Hash object converted from XML string
def xml_to_hash(xml)
  Crack::XML.parse(xml)
end

#
# Fetch lca_data from Hash response
# Response with error will be converted to empty array
# @param [Hash] hash - response
# @return [Array] lca data from response. Empty array if invalid data provided
def lca_data(hash)
  data = hash['root']['lca_data']['prefix']
  data.is_a? Hash ? [data] : Array(data)
rescue NoMethodError
  []
end

#
# Fetch lca_data from XML string (see #lca_data)
# @param [String] xml - string from where to fetch lca_data
# @return [Array] lca data from response.  Empty array if invalid data providede
def lca_data_from_xml(xml)
  lca_data(xml_to_hash(xml))
end

# Main function
def main
  src   = Mysql.new(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
  rs    = src.query('SELECT * FROM npanxx')
  hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new
  rs.each_hash do |row|
    npa, nxx = row['npa'], row['nxx']
    request  = lca_request(npa, nxx)
    request.on_complete do |response|
      lca_data = lca_data_from_xml(response.body)
      lca_data.each do |lca|
        src.query("INSERT INTO npanxxlca (npa,nxx,tnpa,tnxx,texch) VALUES (#{npa}, #{nxx}, #{lca['npa']}, #{lca['nxx']}, #{lca['exch']})")
      end
    end
    hydra.queue(request)
  end
  hydra.run
end

puts Benchmark.measure { main }.real
```

I have little experience working with `MySQL`, so I can't recommend how to optimize that part.

Comment: I didn't test the final code because my MySQL server and database are not set up. So if you have any questions or problems, please let me know. And if that works I am very curious how fast :)

Comment: I'm liking this approach, but I am running into a problem when there is only 1 entry returned, I'm getting array of arrays, instead of arrays of hashes: ["npa", "907"], ["nxx", "221"], ["exch", "003650"], ["ocn", "3023"], ["company_name", "UNITED UTILITIES, INC."], ["rc", "Birch Creek"], ["region", "AK"]]npa.rb:65:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
 from npa.rb:65:in `block (3 levels) in main'

Comment: @zevlag, I updated `lca_data` method to make sure we return an array of hashes.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to insert multiple rows, I think it's the bottleneck.First, you could keep the values in a array, when the array is big enough, then insert multiple rows, like this.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Look at [how-to-insert-multiple-records-into-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803705/how-to-insert-multiple-records-into-database.)

Comment: I like to stop at 100 rows or 1MB, whichever comes first.