# How to insert multiple rows based on a defaults table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have the following tables: Users, Default Prices, Clients, Client Prices. What I'd like is to have the default_prices automatically fill in the client_prices table when a new client is created. It looks like I might be able to use a similar solution to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4327831/1158929). What I would like to happen is when a new client is created by a user, all of the client_prices for the client are populated by the default_prices table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :stripe_token, :default_prices_attributes
  has_many :default_prices
  has_many :clients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :default_prices, :allow_destroy => true


class DefaultPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :user_id, :visit_type, :id
  belongs_to :user
end


class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :address_1, :address_2, :city, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :state, :user_id, :zip, :client_prices_attributes
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :client_prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_prices_attributes


class ClientPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :client_id, :visit_type, :id
  belongs_to :uclient
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add before_create block to copy default price.

```
before_create do
  user.default_prices.each do |default_price|
    client_prices.build(default_price.attributes.slice("price", "visit_type"))
  end
end
```