# What takes the time when doing a Rails CSV import to Postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv

I have a CSV with 950 rows that I'm importing into Postgres via Rails using the following controller code:

```
io = params[:file]
trade_plans = []
CSV.foreach(io.tempfile, { :col_sep => "|" }) do |row|
  if row.length == 16
    trade_plans << create_trade_plan(row)
  end
end
TradePlan.create(trade_plans)



def create_trade_plan(row)

  number_of_shares = row[10].to_i.abs

  return {
    :user_id => current_user.id,
    :symbol => row[2].upcase,
    :symbol_long_name => row[3].upcase,
    :direction => STYPE_MAP[row[5]][1],
    :number_of_shares => number_of_shares,
    :description => "Trade #{row[1]} on #{format_datetime(row[7], row[8])}",
    :trade_status => 'closed',
    :is_potential => false,
    :planned_entry_price => 0,
    :planned_target_price => 0,
    :planned_stop_loss_price => 0,
    :without_trade_plan => true
  }
end
```

I'm using activerecord's bulk `create` method, though from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784305/batch-insertion-in-rails-3/15784888#15784888) it would seem that bulk insert isn't supported for Postgres... anyway, what I'd like to know is that my Rails logs give me this:

```
Completed 200 OK in 315855ms (Views: 1280.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3341.2ms)
```

If there were only 3.3 seconds of AR, how did the import take 315 seconds for 950 rows? There's a few callbacks and some validations but that seems a lot to me. Is 0.33 seconds per record a reasonable expectation?

Comment: Is each insert being done in its own transaction or batched? Are there any foreign keys present on the tables? What does an `explain analyze` of one of the underlying `insert`s show (see the PostgreSQL logs, possibly with `log_statement = 'all'` enabled). Can you just use the Pg gem's support for PostgreSQL's `COPY` to do a fast streaming import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby processing also takes time. Use [benchmarking](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) to see what part of the code takes time.

Comment: It turns out there were some pretty slow callbacks going on. I was sure I'd checked that but investigating with the benchmarking module helped me to get there. Thanks.