# Best Ways to Modify Spree for Bulk Insertion of InventoryUnit Records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, spree

I'm working on an existing Spree application (using Rails 4.2.1 and mysql), and the insertion of InventoryRecords one at a time is killing the performance (during checkout for sure).

When researching the problem, I found this as a suggestion, but it uses the copy command in PostgreSQL, which MySQL doesn't appear to have:

https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/4216#issuecomment-32556519

I've also found a few recommendations to use the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem, but not necessarily with Spree:

[Batch insertion in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784305/batch-insertion-in-rails-3#answer-15806834)

This article benchmarks a few techniques, including the aforementioned:

http://blog.elentok.com/2012/08/activerecordpostgresql-mass-insertion.html

It seems clear that using the COPY command is the most efficient, but being that I'm limited to MySQL, what's the best solution?

Comment: You may be interested in this old pull request which was not merged. It added a quantity for inventory units to deal with some issues like this: https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/4741  It adds a quantity to inventory units to deal with performance issues around inserting large amounts of the same variant.

Comment: @gmacdougall Do you know if spree/spree#4741 was adapted to Solidus? I think this would be good to get in.